# Is it possible to install NuGet on a Mac?

Tags: mac, visual-studio

I am trying to get [Math.NET Numerics for F#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp/). It seems like the only way to do it is to install the [NuGet Package Manager Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console).

However, after downloading [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/), I try to click on `nuget.exe`, and I get the message:

> You can’t open the application “nuget.exe” because Microsoft Windows applications are not supported on OS X.

Is there any way to get NuGet to work on a Mac?

Comment: Mac and Windows are different OS's, but you can get Windows emulators for the Mac that *might* run it (as Wine would in Linux).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I work on Xamarin Components Team with nuget on a daily basis.

Install mono and use:

```
mono nuget.exe
```

It is possible to install nuget via brew too:

```
brew install nuget
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET is now supported on macOS, both for Intel macs and M1 M2 M3 etc macs. You can download the .NET SDK from [Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) and then use the CLI tool `dotnet`. To add a NuGet package run

`dotnet add [package]`

For more NuGet related commands you can do

`dotnet nuget --help`